# What is the right name for plant base protection wraps?

Tags: terminology, support, protection

Sometimes you'll see trees or other larger plants wrapped with a cylindrical hard yet flexible plastic wrap that expands (cut along the length of the tube - not stretching) as the plant grows and helps protect it and or support it. What is the name of this?

For smaller plants I can just use heat-shrink tubing and make a cut myself.

Comment: is the wrap to protect from winter cold or ice damage?  What is the purpose of the wrap?

Comment: Could be. Multi-purpose item really. Protection/support are my uses.

Comment: Can you add some more details to your question as I'm not sure what you are asking.  Protection and support for what? evergreens, fruit trees, annual vegetables?

Comment: Small saplings I guess or tomatoes.

Comment: I removed the 'where can I get it' part, as that changes often, and we prefer not to include that in this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're called tree shelters or tree guards, but there are other types of shelter for other plants. The only ones I know about are made by a company called Tubex in the UK, not sure if they supply outside Europe. There are also spiral tree guards, which are meant to go around the trunk or stem - Ebay in the UK currently has them available, maybe they're online wherever you are too. Some expand, some have to be repositioned as the plant grows, but if you look up tree guard or tree shelter, you should get some information as to what's available.

Answer (score 4):

I use [vinyl tree guards](http://www.agriculturesolutions.com/products/growing-and-propagating/tree-wraps-and-guards/vinyl-tree-guard-wrap-36-pack-of-20-detail) for this, when planting out trees. They look like this:

[image] [image]

They are reusable, and if you find a good supplier, they're extremely cheap.

Comment: Some cities use white four inch drain pipe with a vertical cut. Not as easy to put on but more durable when the whipper snippers come out.

Comment: @kevinsky Bugs like nesting in those better, but yeah, they can work too.